QGIS report: attribute table and "fix" elements on multiple pages
I have a simple report on QGIS LTR.
It is just a "static section" with an attribute table.
On the first page, I have a title and a subtitle. And the attribute table starts a bit lower on th first page than on the second page. I also selected the "repeat until the end", so that if the table needs more pages, it is ok.

The problem appears when it needs to go on multiple other pages. The attribut table is ok, but the rest of the pages are empty. In the exemple, the 2 red lines are not repeated, but it could be page number, title and so on...

I can't find a way to have all these "fix" elements in further pages.

I have encountered the same problem. There is currently no tool in QGIS to solve this problem for all pages “in batch” without using Python. The way I solved the problem was to create several pages and manually customize them, so that all the required table frames, headers and labels were in place.
After that, I selected the “Don't export page if frame is empty” option in the table frame settings.
Unfortunately, this is suitable only if you have quite a small number of pages.
Preparing 30 or more pages using this method is quite time consuming.
Example project.7z


Are you sure? Cause I tested, and it think it only works if I have only the table… but if I have a « static » text, line or something else, the page is exported! Plus if I have page number AND number of page, the last one will be wrong!

@katagena Yes, it works. See Example project.7z.

I made a « feature request » on GitHub!
